# Empty string supplied as input when parsing HTML in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a Wordpress plugin, therefore, I'm trying to manipulate my DOM (the post content). Currently I have this code:

```
<?php
function mb_find_my_image( $content ) {
    if( is_home() ) { /* if is home start */

      $dom = new domDocument;
      $dom->loadHTML($content);
      $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;


    } /* if is home end */
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'mb_find_my_image' );
?>
```

But I always get the following error:

> Empty string supplied as input

I have tried using any other custom string that has html elements and it works. Also I've tried using var_export($content, true ), and this somewhat fixes the problem, but I get errors such as:

> Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object

What I'm I doing wrong?
I'm running this script on my local computer using WAMP Server.

var_dump($content) gives me:

> null 
>   string post content (actual html that is the post) ... (length=805)

Comment: It seems like you are not passing the parameter correctly. Check where you are calling your function and see what's being passed in.

Comment: @KyleGibbens Could you please tell me how to do that? I'm still new to PHP and Wordpress.

Comment: Inside which file is your `mb_find_my_image` function located?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Wordpress, but find where the function is being called from (CTRL+F 'mb_find_my_image' on your source code) and var_dump the value passed in. Again, I'm not very familiar with Wordpress. If Wordpress calls the function using that 'add_filter' function, then makes sure your content is valid HTML.

Comment: @dalbaeb this function is located in functions.php file

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. The main problem was that I was calling the function (mb_find_my_image) from index.php, after I've removed the calling from index.php everything works as it should.